# Cucumber 4, how to skip the scenario and mark the Scenario as Passed?

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

The cucumber scenario is run with the JUnit.

I have a use case, where I need to skip the particular cucumber scenario from executing based on the status of the Jira ticket. I need then that scenario to be marked as Passed in the html report.

I can skip the scenario easily enough with PendingException() or AssumptionViolatedException(), both work OK to skip the scenario execution and mark steps as Skipped. But the scenario itself will be marked as Failed and I wanted it to be Passed.

Anyway I can achieve this? Is there anyway to force the scenario status in to Passed state?

The current code is something like this:

```
 @Before
 public void before(final Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        skipAndSetScenarioToPass(scenario);
    }

    void skipAndSetScenarioToPass (Scenario scenario) {
        throw new PendingException("skipping");
    }
```

Comment: Which report tool are you using?

Comment: cucumber html plugin 'de.monochromata.cucumber:reporting-plugin:2.0.0', which calls this one: https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin

Comment: Then the short answer is no. Perhaps you can put some code in your build pipe that excludes the feature based on a tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I can do that, but the whole point is not to exclude it, otherwise it will confuse management big time. The idea is to present the same report but with different status of the tests based on whether they fail with a known issue or new one.

Comment: Hah. Well, perhaps you can fork the report tool to report skipped scenarios as passed. That's about all you can do.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have to do it seems. We considered doing that, but then kind of didn't like the idea of maintaining our version of the plugin...

Answer (score 0):

If you use [TestNG](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#bdd)  you can throw [SkipException](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.1/org/testng/SkipException.html) instead of `PendingException` which result in status `skip` insteadof `fail` which is more appropriate. You also can modify status to `pass` through [IInvokedMethodListener](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.1/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html) by changing result to `pass` in `afterInvocation` method, which is not recommended as it is false positive!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am using Cucumber JVM (JUnit) not TestNG, so that solution won't work in my case.